# XSS via CSS selector

Tags: xss

BurpSuit detected DOM based XSS on following code.

```
var C=window.location.hash.substring(1);
$("div[data-hash="+C+"]").length>0
```

Can anyone suggest a XSS payload for this?

Comment: What is the remaining of this code and where else is the variable `C` being used?

Comment: This is the only code where C is used.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of was executing JS via CSS expressions in old Internet Explorer versions but my few attempts have all failed.

It should be noted though that an attacker can introduce errors in your page by supplying a payload that causes an invalid CSS selector:

```
var C=window.location.hash.substring(1);
$("div[data-hash="+C+"]").length>0
```

Where *C* contains garbage like `'"foo"'` resulting in an invalid css selector.